# Changing direction of notes

Tags: lilypond

Here, the last chord has a line that goes down.

[image: Notes going up]

How do I get the last chord to be directed upwards, like this?

[image: Notes going down]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At any point, you can input `\stemUp` to impact all succeeding stems in that voice. You can revert that behavior with `\stemNeutral`. I'll let you guess what `\stemDown` does!

Comment: Okay thanks! I just realized that you need to put `\stemUp` _before_ the note! Thanks for helping!